# MaxBackupIndex in logback

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback, slf4j

I have a java project
I am using Logback as a logging framework instead of the  log4j project.
Logback's architecture is sufficiently generic so as to apply under different circumstances.
I have this `logback.xml` file expecting no more than 10 log files at the same time, but Its not the case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>Calzada.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>ATrackAT1Handler.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10KB</maxFileSize>

            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>     
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>CalzadaError.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>ATrackAT1HandlerError.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10KB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>     
    </appender>



    <logger name="com.calzada" level="debug"
        additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

   <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your configuration is mixing up Logback policies.

In your configuration you use: `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` and then attempt to set `minIndex` and `maxIndex` but those configuration properties are not available on a `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`, instead they are properties of a `FixedWindowRollingPolicy`.

See the docs for [TimeBasedRollingPolicy](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy) and [FixedWindowRollingPolicy](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FixedWindowRollingPolicy).

Here are some examples:

- The following appender definition will cause `Calzada.log` to be rolled over to `ATrackAT1Handler.%i.log` everytime `Calzada.log` reaches **10KB** and Logback will retain a maximum of **10 historic files** i.e. `ATrackAT1Handler.1.log` to `ATrackAT1Handler.10.log`

  ```
  <appender name="FILE-AUDIT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
      <file>Calzada.log</file>
      <encoder>
          <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
          <fileNamePattern>ATrackAT1Handler.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
          <minIndex>1</minIndex>
          <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
      </rollingPolicy>
      <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
          <maxFileSize>10KB</maxFileSize>
      </triggeringPolicy>
  </appender>
  ```
- The following appender definition will cause `Calzada.log` to be rolled over to `ATrackAT1Handler.<yyy-MM-dd>.%i.log` everytime `Calzada.log` reaches **10KB** and Logback will retain a maximum of **10 days** of historic log files but (and this is an important distinction) there is no cap on the number of files Logback will rollover *within each day*. So, you could have `ATrackAT1Handler.2017-09-06.0.log` to `ATrackAT1Handler.2017-09-06.20.log` and then the next day you could have  `ATrackAT1Handler.2017-09-07.0.log` to `ATrackAT1Handler.2017-09-07.12.log` etc.

  ```
  <appender name="FILE-AUDIT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
      <file>Calzada.log</file>
      <encoder>
          <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
          <fileNamePattern>ATrackAT1Handler.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
          <maxFileSize>10KB</maxFileSize>
          <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
      </rollingPolicy>
  </appender>
  ```

So, `FixedWindowRollingPolicy` allows you to control the number and size of historic files whereas `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` allows you to control the number of days of historic files and the size of each file. There seems to be a piece missing with `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`, namely, how can we limit the total size of all files across all days? To fill this gap the `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` provides the configuration property: `totalSizeCap`. From the docs:

> **totalSizeCap**  int
>
> The optional totalSizeCap property controls the total size of all archive files. Oldest archives are deleted asynchronously when the total size cap is exceeded. The totalSizeCap property requires maxHistory property to be set as well. Moreover, the "max history" restriction is always applied first and the "total size cap" restriction applied second.

So, you can either go with `FixedWindowRollingPolicy` and you'll limit the number of files but you won't have daily rollovers or use `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` to get daily rollovers and retain *some* control over historic log file footprint by ising `totalSizeCap`.